# How do you indicate that two or more characters are speaking at the same time in a comic?

Tags: formatting, comics

How do you indicate that two or more characters are speaking at the same time in a comic? It would be easy if they said the same thing, then you would just have them share a text bubble, but what if they are saying different things? Is it possible to show that the characters are speaking at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to show characters are speaking at the same time is to overlap their speech-bubbles.

If one is speaking over the other, then you can just cover some of the text of the other so it can't be read at all. If they're equally audible, you can mix the text by using transparency.

The first kind is similar to what TV tropes shows under [speech bubble interruption](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpeechBubblesInterruption)

[image: example of overlapping speech bubbles]

Below is a (self-made) illustration including other types of simultaneous speech, including the one mentioned by @StuartF in the comments.

[image: four types of simultaneous speech bubbles]

The top-left one is a bit of a chaotic mess. But it illustrates how hard it can be to understand people when they talk through each other. You can vary how much overlap there is, and will end up with the top-right situation when there's no overlap.

Comment: You could also blend the speech bubbles into each other so that they're joined but each speaker's words are separate, I can't find an example right now.

Comment: prefect example. It's also the horizontal level of the balloons, reading from top to bottom. One text slightly precedes the other, with clear overlap.